# Angular testing always passing test even if it is wrong

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have this unit test for this observable:

```
fdescribe('goToPurchases', () => {
    it('should have working NavApiService',() => {
        apiService.goToPurchases(null).subscribe((res: PurchaseResponse) => {
            expect(res.shimentId).toBe('not supposed to be valid!')
            expect(res.url).not.toBeDefined();
        });
    });

});
```

this is real method in apiService.ts:

```
public goToPurchases(shipmentId: string): Observable<Object> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${environmentVariables.loadInsurance.apiUrl}/v1/purchases`, {shipmentId});
}
```

The real response should be something like this:

```
{
  "id": "50d4ad69-0337-4e49-8f00-5c9a152cfad0",
  "shipmentId": null,
  "userId": "41ac2d3d-b2ed-4c73-9c56-25d17a9caa7e",
  "url": "https://test.portal.loadsure.net/insureLoad/v2?id=TFMtREFULzIwMjEwODMxL3l6ZDVlYlJRejdrQkdKcUwxbk5l"
}
```

When I run the test it passes successfully? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a type `shimentId` (p missing), probably not the reason but please double check.

Comment: Do you expect real http call to be made?? I dont see any attempt to use http mocking....

Answer (score 1):

By having the expectation into the subscribe callback, you are correctly able to evaluate it once a value is retrieved.
The problem is the test completes before waiting for the response. By completing this way and as it doesn't evaluate anything, the test is a success.

You need to change the way the test completes.

You can use `fakeasync` so your test will only complete once all async tasks are done:

```js
import { fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

fdescribe('goToPurchases', fakeAsync(() => {
    it('should have working NavApiService',() => {
        apiService.goToPurchases(null).subscribe((res: PurchaseResponse) => {
            expect(res.shimentId).toBe('not supposed to be valid!')
            expect(res.url).not.toBeDefined();
        });
    });

}));
```